# CSV Column into ASP DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate an ASP dropdownlist with a column from a CSV. I was able to do it with the below code, however, it shows duplicates since another one of the columns' values are all unique (so using .distinct() is no good). Here is an example of my CSV entries:

env,app,srvrole,servers
Dev,appname1,web,server01
Production,appname1,cache,server02

The servers column is always unique.

Here is my code:

```html
var collection_of_objects =
            (from line in File.ReadAllLines("\\server\\shares\\App\\Farms.csv").Skip(1)
            let parts = line.Split(',')
            select new
            {
               env = parts[0],
               app = parts[1],
               srvrole = parts[2],
               servers = parts[3],
             }
                ).ToList();
           dropdown_app.DataSource = collection_of_objects.Distinct();
           dropdown_app.DataTextField = "app";
           dropdown_app.DataBind();

           srvrole.DataSource = collection_of_objects.Distinct();
           srvrole.DataTextField = "srvrole";
           srvrole.DataBind();
```

I also attempted to use Streamreader and output to a Datatable, however, I could not assign the Datatable to the datasource of the dropdown. TYIA

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using streamreader. If there are any easier ways to do this, I am all ears!

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> environment = new List<String>();
            List<string> application = new List<String>();
            List<string> serverrole = new List<String>();
            List<string> servers = new List<String>();
            
            ReadCSV(environment, application, serverrole, servers);
            
            string[] envlist = environment.ToArray();
            string[] applist = application.ToArray();
            string[] srvrolelist = serverrole.ToArray();
            string[] serverlist = servers.ToArray();

            dropdown_app.DataSource = applist.Skip(1).Distinct();
            dropdown_app.DataBind();

            srvrole.DataSource = srvrolelist.Skip(1).Distinct();
            srvrole.DataBind();

        }

        public static void ReadCSV(List<string> environment, List<string> application, List<string> serverrole, List<string> servers) 
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"\\server\shares\App\Reference\Farms.csv"));

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split(',');
                    if (values.Length >= 4)
                    {
                        environment.Add(values[0]);
                        application.Add(values[1]);
                        serverrole.Add(values[2]);
                        servers.Add(values[3]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```